# How to snip Django TextField?

Tags: python, django-models

I want to create a simple blog using Django, this is my code :

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    content = models.TextField(max_length = 10000)
    publication_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image',verbose_name = 'My photos',blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I display the **content** field, I don't know how to add images (in the body of **content** field) , strong text, ...
Is there anyone can show me how to do this?, sorry if it's a silly question, 
I've searched for hours but I didn't find out the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to be done using Rich text editors. See the list of available django packages [here](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/wysiwyg/). [CKEditor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ckeditor/5.0.2) and [TinyMCE](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tinymce) are promising to easily handle images.